How to make use of cert.pem and key.pem to make ElasticSearch (8.x) from http to https in windows
I have ElasticSearch service running on http in windows server. Also I have existing cert.pem and key.pem which are used for other applications.
How I can make ElasticSearch from http to https by using existing cert.pem and key.pem on windows server?
